# ycsb load data into redis cannot find the data

Tags: java, linux, macos, redis, nosql

My question is where is the data loaded by YCSB? I already tried the following directories:

```
/cellar/redis 
/etc/redis    
/var/redis
```

Where is the data loaded by ycsb? I used home brew to install redis, after that, I was testing redis performance by using YCSB benchmark, it seems fine running workload and loading workload. However I did not create any directory to store the data, I cannot find the data anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a in-memory database, which means that the data you're storing in it isn't on disk (excluding persistence files), but rather in RAM.

Comment: i wont be able to find on my computer? how can i check the stored data

Comment: You can use `redis-cli` to connect to your local Redis instance and browse/examine the data